# Rails simple form put/patch request go as post requests for some objects alone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, ruby-on-rails-5

We have form like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@venue, url: url, method: method) do |f| %>
 <%= render  "shared/errors", object: venue%>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <%= f.association :partner, input_html: { class: "form-control", value: partner.try(:id)  }, label_html: { class: 'control-label' } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <%= f.input :name, input_html: { class: "form-control"  }, label_html: { class: 'control-label' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
      <%= f.input :description, required: true,label: 'About', input_html: { class: "form-control", rows: 5 }, label_html: { class: 'control-label' }  %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I pass the `method` as `:put` I get a hidden field like this in the form

```
<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form edit_venue" id="edit_venue_19" action="/admin/venues/19" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

For some objects the code is being submitted to the update action as expect but for some it goes as a post request. Is this a bug in rails? Or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Usually "post" request for a create action but "put" for an update action

Comment: yeah @AlexKojin but this is a update not a create.

Answer (score 5):

Not all browsers supporting `put` or `patch`. Rails solves this problem with the `_method` field. Rails has a Rack Middleware which rewrites the `HTTP POST` to `HTTP PUT` when the form sends the `_method=put`. If you take a look on your Rails console you can the that you receive a `put`/`update` request.